# integrating php mysql and voip and text to speech

Tags: php, mysql, voip

Im looking for a starting point of writing an application that will allow a php/mysql program to interact with a VOIP caller(s).

The idea is caller calls into a number, and that number reads text output from php/mysql based on menu options on the call.

Where do i start with this project? Specifically, getting the voip to interact with the php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.voicePHP.com](http://www.voicePHP.com)

Comment: This link doesn't appear to have any downloadable content, code or libraries, nor even a product for sale. You can apparently request to join the beta though.

Comment: Indeed, it's only beta for now. As the footer says its "Powered by TringMe", they have additional examples and services www.tringme.com

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Twilio's service](http://www.twilio.com/) too. Language-agnostic, simple REST API, reasonable pay-per-minute cost, very robust and scalable. There are some [examples in the documentation](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/twiml/) that get you started towards doing what you want.